# Wrong projection reference in coordinate system Modifying original coordinate system in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

Working in Germany, where Gauss_Kruger is very often used (as well as ETRS1989_zone 32N), and trying to find out about WKID when I realised that on my machine, the projection reference of the DHDN_3_Degree_Gauss_Zone_3 is set on Transverse Mercator, whereas for Gauss_Kruger 1,2,4 or 5, it's set on Gauss_Kruger, which makes sense.

[image]

I have compared with the Parameters on other machines, where they are correct (Gauss_Kruger). Somehow, I have changed them and I need to modify, and not by setting a new custom Coordinate System but by modifying the file within ArcGIS or even, deleting it. Now I read things there is no Coordinate System Folder but " Instead, a virtual directory structure is built directly from the coordinate system data."    (http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39488)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out how this is occurring. I stepped back in time, and I can't find an occurrence where 31467 ever used Transverse Mercator for the projection name. It would be quite unusual because I usually copy and paste definitions when setting up a set of zones like this, so I would expect all zones to have Transverse Mercator.

You're correct that at ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2, we removed the prj files, so the software should be reading the definition directly from the pe.dll. The only ways I can think of a way to override this, is if you have set an operating system environment variable called PEOBJEDITHOME and redefined 31467 there. Another possibility is if you have a data layer that does have Transverse Mercator as part of the definition.

However, in ArcGIS, Transverse Mercator = Gauss-Krueger. Beyond the "wrong" name, both definitions will give you the exact same results.

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and the disclosure !). Could you please expand on both advices? Should the variable be something like WKID (31467) = WKID(31494) ? As for the second point, does that mean there is somewehre a FC in 31467 with the projection reference set on Transverse Mercator and this could be where the Problem is?

Answer (score 1):

An old Shapefile projected in GK3 although with a Transverse Mercator as Projection System was found and deleted. After restarting the PC Computer, all Settings for GK3 are now consistent across the different zones.